# How can I simplify this "variable as template parameter" in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How can I simplify this Code?

```
mfer::i_value* make_empty_value(mfer::tag tag_)
{
    if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_ble) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_ble>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_chn) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_chn>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_blk) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_blk>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_seq) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_seq>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_man) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_man>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_ivl) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_ivl>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_sen) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_sen>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_wfm) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_wfm>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_pre) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_pre>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_off) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_off>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_nul) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_nul>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_pnt) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_pnt>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_nte) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_nte>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_txc) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_txc>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_flt) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_flt>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_skw) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_skw>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_mss) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_mss>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_pnm) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_pnm>());
    } else if (tag_ == mfer::tag::mwf_pid) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_pid>());
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Briefly stating,

- mfer::tag is enumeration, defined like `enum tag {};` in namespace mfer.
- mfer::i_value is abstract class.

  ```
  class i_value {};
  ```
- mfer::t_value is templated class like,

  ```
  template <mfer::tag tag_type>
  class t_value : public i_value {};
  ```

At this moment, I don't know how to simplify `this make_empty_value()`.

Ideally, I want to make it like this:

```
mfer::i_value* make_empty_value(mfer::tag tag_)
{
    return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<tag_>());
}
```

But I know that it is template, so above one doesn't make sense.

Is there any idea simplify this code? (Some modern C++ features, Boost libraries, and so on)

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Post it as the text in the answer.

Comment: You can change these `if`s to `switch/case` if `mfer::tag::mwf_*` are constants. This may enhance readability.

Comment: Can you share the definition of the `t_value` class?  At least the relevant parts where `tag_type` influences the definition of this class.  It's quite possible, based on what you are doing, that `t_value` doesn't have to be a template class at all.  tag_type could be passed into the constructor.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks for your advice. And more, is there any essential solution for this code? I think switch conversion will help but it couldn't solves essential complexity of this code.

Comment: @selbie It's my fault but sharing codes will be hard, because it will be long. But it is clear, class `t_value` is strongly related with tag_type.

Comment: I would use a `switch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little template work, we can get the factory function down to:

```
i_value* make_empty_value(tag tag_type)
{
    static constexpr auto factory = make_factory(all_tags());

    auto index = std::size_t(tag_type - tag::first);
    if (index < tag::ntags) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(factory[index]());
    }
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Full code below.

The i_value generator map is built at compile time, allowing constant-time lookup.

constraints:

- the values in the enum must be consecutive, but they need not begin at zero.
- this demo requires c++14. It can be easily adapted to work with c++11. For c++03 we'd want to reach out to boost mpl or boost_pp.

complete working example:

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

// minimal implementation of virtual base
class i_value {
public:
    virtual void prove() const = 0;
    virtual ~i_value() = default;
};

// tag enum - note that we have supplied some extra introspection information
// these could just as well be constexpr integers outside the enum
enum tag
{
    ble,
    chn,
    blk,
    seq,

    first = ble,                // first available tag
    last = seq,             // last available tag
    ntags = last-first      // number of tags
};

/// Function to offset an index sequence by the distance from
/// zero to the first available tag - in case the first tag is not zero
template<std::size_t...tags>
constexpr auto tag_offset(std::index_sequence<tags...>)
{
    return std::index_sequence<(tags + tag::first)...>();
}

/// Function to compute an index sequence of all valid tags
constexpr auto all_tags()
{
    return tag_offset(std::make_index_sequence<std::size_t(ntags)>());
}

/// Factory function to generate a derived class for a given tag
template <tag tag_type>
class t_value : public i_value {
    void prove() const override { void(std::cout << "I have tag " << tag_type << std::endl); }
    ~t_value() { void(std::cout << "tag " << tag_type << " destroyed" << std::endl); }
};

template<tag tag_type>
i_value* make_instance()
{
    return new t_value<tag_type>();
}


/// Function to generate a 'factory' - an array of factory functions, one for
/// each tag in the variadic template argument tags...
/// Note that the array is zero-based, the tags may not be. All we care about
/// here is the size of the list of tags (and their values)
///
template<std::size_t...tags>
constexpr auto make_factory(std::index_sequence<tags...>)
{
    return std::array<i_value* (*)(), sizeof...(tags)>
    {
        &make_instance<static_cast<tag>(tags)>...
    };
}

// minimal memory manager
struct memory_manager {
    struct impl {
        i_value* add(i_value* item) {
            _ivalues.push_back(item);
            return item;
        };
        ~impl() {
            for (auto i = _ivalues.rbegin() ; i != _ivalues.rend() ; ++i) {
                delete *i;
            }
        }
        std::deque<i_value*> _ivalues;
    };
    static impl& instance()
    {
        static impl _instance = {};
        return _instance;
    }
};

// here is resulting factory function.
i_value* make_empty_value(tag tag_type)
{
    static constexpr auto factory = make_factory(all_tags());

    auto index = std::size_t(tag_type - tag::first);
    if (index < tag::ntags) {
        return memory_manager::instance().add(factory[index]());
    }
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

// test
int main()
{
    for(auto tag_type : { tag::ble, tag::chn })
    {
        auto pvalue = make_empty_value(tag_type);
        pvalue->prove();
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
I have tag 0
I have tag 1
tag 1 destroyed
tag 0 destroyed
```

Comment: Can I ask why you wrapped void() at functions of t_value? It makes any better one?

Comment: Believe it or not, wrapping ostream operations in void prevents xcode from misformatting the code. It also happens to be a portable way of indicating that you're deliberately ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the tags to a factory method;

```
typedef std::unordered_map<mfer::tag,std::function<mfer::i_value*()>> TagMap;

TagMap create_tag_map()
{
    TagMap map;

    map[mfer::tag::mwf_ble] = [](){ return new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_ble>(); };
    map[mfer::tag::mwf_chn] = [](){ return new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_chn>(); };
    map[mfer::tag::mwf_blk] = [](){ return new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_blk>(); };
    //...

    return map;
}
```

The `create_empty_value` method could then look like this:

```
mfer::i_value* make_empty_value(mfer::tag tag_)
{
    static TagMap factory = create_tag_map();

    auto it = factory.find( tag_ );      
    if( it != factory.end() )
    {
        return  memory_manager::instance().add( it->second() );
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

see simplified version **<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd05ba77fa07d311)</kbd>**

Comment: But then if he only uses this once, he is writing even *more* code to create the factory pattern for a one time use.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recursive template function if the enumerate value follows a known pattern (by default next enumerate value equals previous enumerate +1):

```
  //anonymous namespace to "help innliner"
  namespace{
    //This function return the next enumerates value:
    constexpr mref::tag next_tag(mref::tag tag_) {
      return static_cast<mref::tag>(
          static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<mref::tag>>(tag_) + 1);
    }
    //The compute function is wrapped in a structure to enable template 
    //specialization:
    template <mref::tag Tag> struct add_to_mem_manager {
      static mfer::i_value* compute(mref::tag tag_) {
        if (Tag == tag_) {
           return memory_manager::instance().add(
                new mfer::t_value<Tag>());
        } else {
          return add_to_mem_manager<next_tag(Tag)>::compute(tag_);
        }
      }
    };
    //Specialization for last enumerate
    template <> struct add_to_mem_manager<mfer::tag::mwf_pid> {
      static mref::ivalue* compute(mref::tag tag_) {
        assert(mref::tag::mwf_pid == tag_);
        return memory_manager::instance().add(
                new mfer::t_value<mfer::tag::mwf_pid>());
      }
    };
  }
  mfer::i_value* make_empty_value(mfer::tag tag_){
     //call with template parameter equals to the 
     //the enumerate whose values is the smallest
     return add_to_mem_manager<mfer::tag::mwf_ble>::compute(tag_);
  }
```

If you don't know the constitutive rule of your enumerate, you cannot do this,( generaly constitutive law is as in this example, x[i+1]=x[i]+1, or x[i+1]=x[i]<<1 (left shift).) Otherwise their is no way to iterate over elements of an enumeration.

Note: The function `compute` will certainly be inlined, but in doubt you can use
compiler specific attribute as `__forceinline` with MSVC or `__attribute__((__always_inline__))` with GCC or clang.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly using your example, but you can do something on the below lines, i.e converting enum to a type.

```
enum Type {
  Type_A,
  Type_B,
};

template <Type T>
struct Enum2Type {
  constexpr static const Type type = T;
};

template <typename T>
mfer::i_value* make_empty_value(T tag_type)
{
    return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<tag_type.type>());
}

auto val = make_empty_value(Enum2Type<Type_A>());
auto val2 = make_empty_value(Enum2Type<Type_B>());
```

Comment: But if I use this code, I can't passing variable through this function, do I?

Comment: If you mean making argument of `make_empty_value ` variable, then no, you can't. Template needs some value that it can see an compile time. At some point you will have to use a switch-case if its a runtime parameter.

Comment: I see. ;( I expected the situation should implement that way will be more usual, so I believed there is pattern for those codes.

Comment: Another way would be to use `tag dispatching` in the constructor of `mfer::t_value`. In that case you wouldn't need to write the switch case in `make_empty_value`, but then will have to create constructor for each enum value. So, you see, at some point you will have to expand all your options if you use runtime parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

The only scope of simplification I see is in removing the boilerplate code by replacing with a fixed macro. This will be soothing to the viewer.

Instead of so many `if-else if`, make it a `switch/case` as below:

```
#define CASE(TAG) \
  case TAG: return memory_manager::instance().add(new mfer::t_value<TAG>())

mfer::i_value* make_empty_value(const mfer::tag tag_)
{
  switch(tag_) {
  {
  CASE(mfer::tag::mwf_ble);
  CASE(mfer::tag::mwf_chn);
  CASE(mfer::tag::mwf_blk);
  //...
  default: break;
  }
  return nullptr;
}

#undef CASE
```